# Problem : Adding not existing contacts to organisations

Tags: relationships

When i open the sheet of organisation in civicrm then i want to add relationship with another contact civi propose only existing contact.

is there way to add new contact in this relationship using the same screen 'add relationship' without using "add new person" in navigation bar?

Answer (score 3):

You do get a option when selecting a contact on add relationship form, 'New individual', 'New Organization' etc. That should allow you to create new contact from the same form

[image]

Comment: thanks for the anwser. So, in my case i dont see "new individual" should i activate something in civi ?

Comment: Do you have a permission to create contact?

Comment: Yes, i can create contact .